# Converting Hex to Base64 with notepad++

Tags: base64, hex, notepad++

I am playing around with converting  Hex value into Base64.

By using notepad++ convertion, for exemple, the value `FB` in Hex is `RkI=` in Base64

and if I use http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en

I get a different value equal to: `+w==`

Actually, this value is the correct one because I get the same value when I just calculate this convertion using a paper and a pen :D

Could anyone please explain how notepad++ make this convertion!?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show how you did the conversion. I cannot find an encode in Base-64 command in Notepad++.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The trick was that by converting the HEX directly in notepad++, It's taken as a ASCII value not as A HEX Value as intended.

So we need to converted first the HEX --> ASCII then ASCII --> BASE64

1/ Select the string

2/ Using Notepad++ menu: **Plugins -> Converter ->** *HEX -> ASCII*

3/ **Plugins -> MIME Tools -> Base64 Encode**

and we get the needed value

Answer (score 3):

The characters `FB` can be encoded as the 16-bit values `46004200` and encoding that in Base 64 gives `RkI=`.

Using Notepad++ menu => **TextFx** => **TextFx Tools** => **Base 64 decode**:

- Converting `+w==` gives the single byte `xFB`. It show as thouse three characters in white on a black background. The status bar at the bottom of the window shows the buffer has a length of `1` (i.e. one).
- Converting `RkI=` gives the two characters `FB`. Shown in black on a white background, i.e. as normal text. The buffer is shown to have a length of 2.

Conclusion, your initial conversion was of the two charactgers `FB` not the byte with value hex-FB.